# Is it possible create a polygon from more polygons that are not overlapped but close and remove gaps between them?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have to create a big polygon with the outer ring from some selected polygons that are close to each other like in the picture.

[image]

Is it somehow possible two fill the small gap between the polygons as shown in the other picture

[image: Polygon]

I'm using this query:

```sql
 SELECT ST_ExteriorRing((ST_DUMP(ST_Union(the_geom))).geom) FROM parcel
```

to get the outer line but get 4 rows result,
What do I've to do to get only one row of the outer line without the gaps

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you also add this geometry e.g. as WKT?

Comment: you could `ST_BUFFER` the polygon by a small amount to fill gaps and slithers, although you'd lose the accuracy of the original polygon shape.